# How does the primary voting algorithm break a tie for 10th place?

Tags: support, election-2012

As a candidate in the [election](https://serverfault.com/election), naturally I was following it closely as Ward and I raced against each other for the 10th spot in the primary. 20-30 minutes before the end of the [primary](https://serverfault.com/election/2?tab=primary) I checked and we were tied. Afterwards I saw that Ward was in the election phase. Much later, out of curiosity, I checked the [primary page](https://serverfault.com/election/2?tab=primary) to see how close Ward and I ended up, and was surprised to see that we both showed the same score.

The primary simply says "the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score proceed onward to the election phase", which doesn't really give any clue how a tie is broken at 10th place, which appears to have happened here.

Assuming primary votes didn't change after the primary concluded, how does the system decide which of two equal scores for the 10th place in the primary proceeds to the election phase?

Comment: Honestly, I'm mostly just curious, since I suspect that candidates who come in 10th in the primary are extremely unlikely to win the main election anyways.

Comment: I'd also be curious to find out what the tiebreaker is.  And for what it's worth, you had my vote - a big pile of rep isn't everything, and the moderation experience on another SE site goes a long way.

Comment: Interesting... you actually had far more + votes than ward (but also, far more -'s)

Comment: ITS A CONSPIRACY!

Comment: @MarkHenderson: Yes, but there were several candidates with substantially more + votes

Comment: I wonder if it is something as simple as looking at the vote split.  Ward: 22/-12, freiheit 27/-17.  You had more down-votes.  Everyone who made it to the general seems to have less then or equal to 12 down-votes.  Hrm.

Comment: See also [the same question on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190005/145951).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event of a tie, the tiebreaker goes to the person who nominated themselves first.

Comment: Gotta love the simplicity of that. :)

Comment: That's not what I was expecting the answer to be...